# Keep the marked row after bindrows() in treetable

Tags: javascript, binding, rendering, refresh, sapui5

I'm trying to build a refresh button for a tree table. After the refresh action (using the `bindrows` method with defined filter condition), the previous marked row need to be kept.
The problem is, after the refresh action, the marked row will disappear. I'm not sure whether the `addEventDelegate()` is a suitable method, because this method doesn't react anything, even if I set a debugger inside the `onAfterRendering()`.
Does anyone have a solution to solve this scenario?

```
onRefresh : function() {
    var oTreeTable = this.getView().byId("treeTable");

    oTreeTable.bindRows({
        path: "/TTBL_Set",
        filters: filterRefresh,
        parameters: {
          countMode: "Request",
          numberOfExpandedLevels: 4
        }
    });

    oTreeTable.addEventDelegate({
        onAfterRendering: function() {              
          oTreeTable.setSelectedIndex(iCurrentSelectedIndex); //iCurrentSelectedIndex is pre-defined 
        }
    }, this);               
},
```

The marked row here in a tree-table need to be kept after refresh event
[image]

Comment: Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by using [Custom Data](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.36.8/docs/guide/91f0c3ee6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html) and [sap.ui.model.Binding](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Binding) `attachDataReceived()`

1.Save the selected row context path inside the row selection method.

```
//inside rowSelectionChange() method
var oTTable = getYourTable;
    oCutsData = {},
    rowContextPath = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath();
    if(oTTable && oTTable.data("selectedRows")){
        oCustData = oTTable.data("selectedRows");//add your new row selection context path and update the object
        oCutsData[rowContextPath] = rowContextPath; 
    }else{//for first selection
        oCutsData = {};
        oCutsData[rowContextPath] = rowContextPath;//create new object
    }
    oTTable.data("selectedRows",oCutsData);
```

2.After the data is received loop the custom data and select the row again

```
var oTTable = this.getView().byId("yourTableID")
    if(oTTable){
        var oRowsBinding = oTTable.getBinding("rows");//Rows Binding
        oRowsBinding.attachDataReceived(function(oEvent){
            var oSelectedRows = oTTable.data("selectedRows");
            if(oSelectedRows){
                var oModel = getYourModel(); //Tree table model
                var sPath = null;//only for one selection
                for(var path in oSelectedRows){
                   sPath = oSelectedRows[path];                    
                }
                //get the row contexts and compare with the previous selected row and select
                var oRowContexts = oTTable._getRowContexts();
                for(var index in oRowContexts){
                   if(oRowContexts[index].context.getPath() === sPath ){
                      //Select the table row using row index
                      oTTable.setSelectedIndex(parseInt(index));
                      break;
                   }
                }
                //after the loop destroy the custom data using destroyCustomData()
                oTTable.destroyCustomData();
            }
        }.bind(this));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @inizio a lot for your detailed description. After I have used your solution into my codes, The outoput of the `oSelectedRows` that I got is a path of the selected row which is also its attribut name( e.g.: `/TTBL_AGGSet(000131) : "/TTBL_AGGSet(000131)" `). And at the end, I still loss my selection on that expected row. Therefore, I have two questions in your codes: 1. How do you become the `getTheContextPAth()`? Do you mean using the combination of methodes like this: `oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath()`?

Comment: 2. In my case the selection is alway single, so the result of `oSelectedRows` contains also only one value. Does that mean I just need to write `oTTable.setSelectedIndex(oSelectedRows.rowContextPath)` within that if-statement? Sorry for these a bunch of questions. I'm a js-beginner with only 2 months experiences.

Comment: 1. Yes you have to use `oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext().getPath()`.
2. Yes inside the if statement you get the previously selected row(path) using  `oTTable.data("selectedRows")` and update the Model property which indicates the checkbox status using the path.

Comment: Thanks for your update. But I still lose my selection on the row after refresh. May I ask why we need a ckeckbox in this case? What I expect is to keep the selected row with marked line in the tree-table. An expected illustration is in my next answer. Do you have any further ideas? Besides, where can I look up the parameters(like Indicator) which can be passed to the methode "setProperty"?

Comment: Both the binding and row are independent of each other. The same row index will not have the same binding. The rows are dynamically created. So I have found a simple way to identify the row using `_getRowContexts()`. I have updated my code. Hope its helps this time. Remove the below answer, I have update it in the question only.

Comment: I made a small change in the code and tested in my local as well. Its working fine for me. Updated `oTTable.setSelectedIndex(index);` to `oTTable.setSelectedIndex(parseInt(index));`.

Comment: Now it works perfectly! Thanks your very much. Besides your helpfull solution, I have modified my codes, which I have posted in my question at the beginning: Instead of the methode `oTreeTable.bindRows({...})` I have used `oTreeTable.getBinding("rows").refresh()` , otherwise it won't work at all. Because the `bindRows(...)` acts like a re-binding action, and any further actions or definitions after that re-binding action will be lost even if we have used `attachDataReceived()`

Comment: Did the codes work in your side, even if you use the `oTreeTable.bindRows({...}) ?` If yes, could you show me your codes?

Comment: I have not used `oTreeTable.bindRows({...})`